# Printing PDF with watermark copy

Tags: vba, pdf, printing, ms-word

I have several external PDF that I want to print with the watermark copy. See picture:
[image: Printing pdf]

So I tried the code below to print the pdf from word, however nothing gets printed, any idea how to achieve this task?

```
    Public Enum actionType
    openfile
    printfile
End Enum



Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
  (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
  ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
  ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Function ExecuteFile(fileName As String, action As actionType)
' action can be either "Openfile" or "Printfile".

Dim sAction As String

  Select Case action
    Case 0 ' openfile
      sAction = "Open"
    Case 1 ' printfile
      sAction = "Print"
  End Select

  ShellExecute 0, sAction, fileName, vbNullString, "", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Function

Sub TestPrint()
  ' open a file
  'ExecuteFile "C:\MyFile.xls", openfile
  ' print another
  ExecuteFile "Z:\Prosjekt\32982\Tegninger\PDF\0081606.pdf", printfile
End Sub
```

Comment: [Excel](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?39616-Add-Background-to-PDF-using-Excel-VBA) and [Word](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/vba-to-add-delete-watermark-on-each-page/7f73b736-5da3-4eea-9af1-4629addcd4b4)